No module named 'src', even if it exists
I have a repository project, which is taking me longer than I expected to setup both database and the task (a cron job) both in a smooth way. To test connection, first run the postgres server then create the database:
docker run --rm -d --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=myuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword -p 5432:5432 postgres`
`docker exec -it postgres psql -U myuser -c 'CREATE DATABASE mydb;

This step is somewhat already manual. For that, I wrote a docker-compose, but still stumble on errors like 'Cannot create a database within a transaction'. Anyhow, after run of commands above, we will (or should) be able to run to run a simple script like:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:mypassword@0.0.0.0:5432/mydb")

def app():
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        stmt = text("select * from pg_database")
        print(conn.execute(stmt).fetchall())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()

My initial idea was to parametrize the test within a conftest.py. However, when I import the model from relative path src.database.models in another test file (or in this case conftest), I am not able to because of error log ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from src.database.models import UserDB
from datetime import datetime

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:mypassword@0.0.0.0:5432/mydb")

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def app():
    with Session() as session:
        session.add_all(
            [
                UserDB(
                    id=1,
                    username="John Smith",
                    email="john@mail.com",
                    password="mypwd1234!",
                    created_at=datetime.now(),
                    updated_at=datetime.now()
                ),
                UserDB(
                    id=2,
                    username="Amy Johnson",
                    email="amy@mail.com",
                    password="mypwd1234?",
                    created_at=datetime.now(),
                    updated_at=datetime.now()
                ),
            ]
        )
        session.commit()



    with engine.connect() as conn:
        stmt = select(UserDB)
        print(conn.execute(stmt).fetchall())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()

It is indeed embarrasing to stumble upon such trivial errors, even after searching for 2 days in a row. I can cite other errors as well, but if you can help me with this, it will propel me in further investigations.
[1] https://github.com/brunolnetto/db-cron-docker

Change this line to name = "db-cron".  Move everything under src/* into src/db_cron/*. Change all your import statements to replace src with db_cron.

I made the changes you mentioned. It now complains 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db_cron'' :'-(

This line looks wrong aswell. It should be like packages = [ { include = "db_cron", from = "src" }]. You may need to run poetry install again.

src in a repository layout isn't supposed to be a package; it's a directory that contains both your top-level packages and your scripts.

Friends, I need some help of yours. Without assistance given what I have done so far, I cannot progress much.

Hi, It would be great to structure your question a bit: 1) what is the main problem? Is it about importing schema from "src"? 2) What project structure do you have? Pls show folders. You've provided code for several files, but I guess that they are in different folders, could you please write in the question where each file is located. 3) what test framework are you using? Is it pytest? How do you run it? Are you calling pytest tests? Do you running pytest tests outside the src directory? 4) Do you use pyproject.toml to configure tests? Could you please show the config?
